# SQL group by with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Imagine i have a table like below:

```
ID    Score    someOtherColumns
 1        1    ....
 2        1    .....
 3        4    ....
 5        2    ....
 6        1    ....
```

where score can have an intger value between 0 and 100. I want to group by score, which can be done with something like:

```
Select score, count(*) from myTable group by score;
```

How do I add a condition in the group by if I want to group scores > 20 in one group?

I have tried:

```
Select score, count(*) from myTable
group by 
  case 
    when score >19 then 20
    else score
  end;
```

but get a "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: You need to put the same case expression into your `SELECT` list

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the same expression with `SELECT` statement :

```
Select (case when score > 19 then 20 else score end) as score, count(*) 
from myTable
group by (case when score > 19 then 20 else score end);
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `case` part up as a *derived table* (the subquery). `GROUP BY` its result.

```
select score, count(*)
from
(
    select case 
             when score >19 then 20
             else score
           end as score
    from myTable
) dt
group by score
```

This way you don't need to repeat the case expression, i.e. less error prone.